# iPad with iOS 9.2 issue with accept pdf on input

Tags: html, ipad

We've got a web application with:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf"/>
```

Application must run on iPad. But the problem comes up when user tries to select PDF file from iCloud Drive. All files are available. Image/* works fine (it greys out all non-images).

I've also tried

```
<input type="file" accept=".pdf, application/x-pdf, application/vnd.pdf, text/pdf"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Edit:

Still didn't find any way to fix that. For now, application has validation on server side.

Comment: The same issue.

Comment: Still a problem in iOS 11.0. This is not receiving enough attention.

Comment: I've noticed that if `'image/*' or 'video/*'` is present in the accept string (next to .pdf) it overrides all others (you can only select images). Feels like a bug. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an iOS Safari issue, referenced here :

https://openradar.appspot.com/36726477

Answer (score 0):

The `accept` attribute on an `<input type="file"/>` element is only designed as a **hint** to the user agent (e.g. browser) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Limiting_accepted_file_types

If the user agent can filter out files to match the accept attribute it certainly does improve the user experience - however they are not required to. For iOS it does seem to do something half decent for images & video... and if you add the `capture` attribute you can auto-invoke the camera/video recorder on newer iOS versions.

As such, currently you can specify the `accept` attribute you have. On browsers that support it well, it will filter the available results, however on iOS it won't filter the results.  You'll just have to inform your user that they should be uploading a PDF (and if it really matters, validate it on the server)